# What sort of design pattern should I be using here to make full use of modern C++?

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code for a Calculus program I'm making. All you need to know is that it's part of a recursive procedure that uses the rules of differentiation (`f'(g*h)=f*g'+g*f'`, `(g+f)'=g'+f'`, etc.) to find the derivative of a function represented as a string.

```
std::string _deriveFromNode ( node * nd )
{
    std::string dfdx;
    switch (nd->op)
    {
        case NONE: dfdx = (nd->eq == "x" ? "1" : "0");
        case ADD: dfdx = _deriveFromNode(nd->LHS) + "+" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS);
        case SUB: dfdx = _deriveFromNode(nd->LHS) + "-" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS);
        case MULT: dfdx = nd->LHS->eq + "*" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS) + "+" + nd->RHS->eq + "*" +_deriveFromNode(nd->LHS);
        case DIV: dfdx = "(" + nd->LHS->eq + "*" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS) + "-" + nd->LHS->eq + "*" + _deriveFromNode(nd->LHS);
        case EXP: /* ???? */;
        default: ;
    }
    return dfdx;
}
```

However, I feel like there should be some better design pattern than using a switch statement. Essentially this is mapping a `node` object

```
struct node
{
    std::string eq;
    oper op;
    node * LHS;
    node * RHS;
};
```

to functions, so I feel like I should be using function pointers or something. Can someone give me advice on how to convert the above to something that looks more readable, maintainable and modern?

Comment: You could use a base class and virtual functions, but that has more overhead. Do you want users of your library to be able to define their own operations for use in your code? Or are the operations fixed in your design?

Comment: don't forget to add breaks

Comment: It looks fine to me...

Comment: What you might be looking for is the visitor pattern. Not that I'm suggesting you use it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create functions that deal with the logic of dealing with the various operators. This makes the code look cleaner but it still uses the `switch` statement.

```
// Declare function template.
template <oper op> std::string deriveFromNode(node* nd);

// Define specializations of function template for the 
// known operators.

template <> std::string deriveFromNode<NONE>(node* nd)
{
   return (nd->eq == "x" ? "1" : "0");
}

template <> std::string deriveFromNode<ADD>(node* nd)
{
   return (_deriveFromNode(nd->LHS) + "+" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS));
}

template <> std::string deriveFromNode<SUB>(node* nd)
{
   return (_deriveFromNode(nd->LHS) + "-" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS));
}

template <> std::string deriveFromNode<MULT>(node* nd)
{
   return (nd->LHS->eq + "*" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS) + "+" + nd->RHS->eq + "*" +_deriveFromNode(nd->LHS));
}

template <> std::string deriveFromNode<DIV>(node* nd)
{
   return ("(" + nd->LHS->eq + "*" + _deriveFromNode(nd->RHS) + "-" + nd->LHS->eq + "*" + _deriveFromNode(nd->LHS));
}

template <> std::string deriveFromNode<EXP>(node* nd)
{
   // Fix the logic for this.
   return "";
}

std::string _deriveFromNode ( node * nd )
{
   switch (nd->op)
   {
      case NONE:
         return deriveFromNode<NONE>(nd);

      case ADD:
         return deriveFromNode<ADD>(nd);

      case SUB:
         return deriveFromNode<SUB>(nd);

      case MULT:
         return deriveFromNode<MULT>(nd);

      case DIV:
         return deriveFromNode<DIV>(nd);

      case EXP:
         return deriveFromNode<EXP>(nd);

      default: ;
   }
   return dfdx;
}
```

You can replace the switch the `switch` statement by code that uses a `map` to look up the function to call for various operators. I don't think that is any more elegant or efficient than using a `switch`.

```
std::string _deriveFromNode ( node * nd )
{
   typedef std::string (*function_t)(node* nd);
   std::map<oper, function_t> functions;

   if ( functions.empty())
   {
      // Register the functions corresponding to the operators.
      functions[NONE] = deriveFromNode<NONE>;
      functions[ADD] = deriveFromNode<ADD>;
      functions[SUB] = deriveFromNode<SUB>;
      functions[MULT] = deriveFromNode<MULT>;
      functions[DIV] = deriveFromNode<DIV>;
      functions[EXP] = deriveFromNode<EXP>;
   }

   std::map<oper, function_t>::iterator iter = functions.find(nd->op);
   if ( iter != functions.end() )
   {
      return iter->second(nd);
   }
   else
   {
      // Deal with unknown operator.
   }
}
```

Comment: With this approach you could ditch the whole switch-case and do just `deriveFromNode<nd->op>(nd)`

Comment: @zenith, you can't do that since the value of `nd->op` is not known at compile time.

Comment: Do template function parameters need to be know at compile-time? Okay sorry my bad.

Comment: What's a `function_t`? Of course it sounds pretty trivial, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it. Is it actually a part of the standard library or the language specification?

Comment: No, it's a `typedef` defined locally in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the way you're doing it now is just fine.

You could of course define some function for those operations instead of stuffing everything in the same function, and return them right away, maybe something like this:

```
switch (nd->op)
{
    case NONE: return std::string(nd->eq == "x" ? "1" : "0");
    case ADD: return _addNode(nd);
    case SUB: return _subNode(nd);
    case MULT: return _mulNode(nd);
    case DIV: return _divNode(nd);
    case EXP: /* ???? */;
    default: return "";
}
```

Also don't forget to add the `break` statements to avoid falling to the below cases, if you're not returning right away in each case.